# How to replace unwanted character with string.empty on key up event?

Tags: javascript

I am using `textarea` where I just want to accept numbers, comma and space. What I am trying to achieve is, if the user types in anything else than do not allow.

For example,

```
123 is valid
123a should be 123
1a23v should be 123
```

I tried following approaches but no luck.

Approach-1: This gives me true false but not sure how to remove last entry.

```js
$("#my-text-area").on("keyup", function(value) {
  var regex = new RegExp(/^[0-9, ]*$/);
  var input = this.value;
  var new_value = regex.test(input);
  alert(new_value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="my-text-area"></textarea>
```

Approach-2: Using `subString`

```js
$("#my-text-area").on("keyup", function(value) {
  var regex = new RegExp(/^[0-9, ]*$/);
  if (!regex.test(this.value)) {
    var inputString = this.value;
    //alert(inputString);
    var updatedString = inputString.substr(0, inputString.length - 1)
    alert(updatedString);
    $("my-text-area").val(updatedString);
  } else {
    alert("Valid");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="my-text-area"></textarea>
```

I know that the regex I am using validates what I want.

```js
$("#my-text-area").on("keyup", function(value) {
  var regex = new RegExp(/^[0-9, ]*$/);
  if (!regex.test(this.value)) {
    alert("Invalid");
  } else {
    alert("Valid");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="my-text-area"></textarea>
```

Comment: Use the `keydown` event, not `keyup`.

Comment: Don't do this. It's a bad user experience. The user might feel that his keyboard is broken. Instead, check the input on submit, and display an error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the character is not valid, you must cancel the key event so that the character isn't actually inserted into the textarea. However, this will only work if the event is cancelled prior to the character being placed in the field. To accomplish this, use the `keydown` event instead of the `keyup` event because by the time `keyup` fires, the character is already in the field. You want to test before it is placed in the field. When the code is written this way, you don't have to worry about removing the last (invalid) character from the field.

Now, to test the input, don't test against `this.value` because that is what's already in the textarea (which could be a bad character) and, again, by that time, it's too late to prevent the character from being inserted. Instead, you want to test the `key` that was pressed.

```js
$("#my-text-area").on("keydown", function(evt) {

  var regex = new RegExp(/^[0-9, ]*$/);

  // As long as the user didn't hit backspace, delete or any of the arrow keys....  
  if(evt.keyCode !== 8 && evt.keyCode !== 46 && 
     evt.keyCode !== 37 && evt.keyCode !== 38 && evt.keyCode !== 39 && evt.keyCode !== 40){
  
    // Test the key that was inputted, not the value of the textarea
    if(!regex.test(evt.key)){
       evt.preventDefault();  // Cancel the event
       evt.stopPropagation(); // Prevent event bubbling
    }
    
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="my-text-area"></textarea>
```

Comment: Thanks for the details. That helps.

Comment: One catch though, I cannot use backspace or delete here. Do I need to add it in `regex`?

Comment: @CSharper I have updated the answer to account for this as well as the arrow keys.

Comment: Also, I have noticed that if I want to implement `Ctrl + A`, `Ctrl + C` & `Ctrl + V` then what is my option here. I do not see any `keyCode` for those.  Do I need to use combination of these keys? I found this, `https://codepen.io/jackocnr/pen/ezBKVQ` which uses `keyup` and 'keydown' both.

Comment: @CSharper The `event` object (`evt` in my example) exposes Boolean properties you can test for to determine if CTRL, SHIFT and/or ALT was held down while the main key was pressed. They are `ctrlKey, `shiftKey` and `altKey`,

Comment: I'll try that. Sorry for many questions but want to clear my doubt. On `keyDown` I can read the value after key is pressed. Meaning, if enter `2345` than `this.value` will be `234`. How can I read `2345`? You are not recommending `keyup` for what I am trying to achieve here. I tried `String.fromCharCode(evt.which)` which is same as `evt.key`.

Comment: @CSharper With `keydown` the JavaScript executes before the key is placed in the textarea, so `this.value` will be whatever it was before the key was pressed. And, yes, `evt.key` is the same thing as `String.fromCharCode....`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147378/discussion-between-csharper-and-scott-marcus).

Answer (score 0):

Might this helps to you.

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function Validate(event) {
    var regex = new RegExp("^[0-9-!@#$%*?.,]");
    var key = String.fromCharCode(event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);
    if (!regex.test(key)) {
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
}       
</script>
```

HTML

```
<textarea onkeypress="return Validate(event);"></textarea>
```

Comment: Inline HTML event handlers (`onkeypress`) should not be used. Function names should be in `camelCase`. `PascalCase` should only be used for constructor functions. JQuery (which the OP is using) provides `event.key` to get the key that was pressed, so your code is redundant. Also, your code allows non-numeric input, which the OP doesn't want.